# ordering strings and numbers in php

Tags: php, sorting, type-conversion, usort

I was experimenting with PHP type juggling and found a weired behavior I can't explain. I was sorting objects based on a property that is sometimes a string, sometimes a number. Using usort, some items get out of place. I can't figure out why. I'm using PHP 7.0.16.

```
class Classe {
    protected $data = array();
    public function Set($chave, $valor) {
        $this->data[$chave] = $valor;
    }
    public function Get($chave) {
        return $this->data[$chave];
    }
}
$objetos = array();
$nomes = array('Joao', 'Jose', 'Lucas', 'Antonio', 'Miguel', 'Arthur', 'Davi', 'Bernardo', 'Heitor', 'Gabriel');
$posicoes = array(7, '8.2', '9', 1.0, '5', 1.1, '3.2', '2', '4', 4.2);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $objeto = new Classe;
    $objeto->Set('pos', $posicoes[$i]);
    $objeto->Set('nome', $nomes[$i]);
    $objetos[] = $objeto;
}
foreach ($objetos as $o) {
    echo "{$o->Get('pos')}: {$o->Get('nome')}\n";
}
echo "\nAfter sorting:\n";
usort($objetos,
    function($a, $b) {
        return $a->Get('pos') - $b->Get('pos');
    });

foreach ($objetos as $o) {
    echo "{$o->Get('pos')}: {$o->Get('nome')}\n";
}
```

Order after sorting:

> 1: Antonio
>   1.1: Arthur
>   2: Bernardo
>   3.2: Davi
>   4: Heitor
>   5: Miguel
>   4.2: Gabriel
>   7: Joao
>   8.2: Jose
>   9: Lucas

Notice how items 4.2 and 5 are out of order. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the float value. If you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) you will find:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

And:

> Caution
>   Returning non-integer values from the comparison function, such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we need to look at the array sorting options available in the SPL (http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). We want to sort by value using alphanumeric characters, AND we do not care about key/value association. That really opens up our options.

Try some of the other array sort options in place of `usort(...)`. I have eyt to find a sorting pattern that was not covered.